# Alternate proof of the Caro-Wei theorem for lower bounding the independence number

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices whose degree sequence is $d_1,d_2,...,d_n$. Let $\alpha(G)$ denote the size of maximum independent set of $G$, i.e., the size of a maximum subset of vertices of $G$ that are pairwise non-adjacent. So Caro-Wei says that $\alpha(G) \geq \sum_{d_i \in V(G)}{\frac{1}{1+d_i}}$. The standard probabilistic proof goes as follow, here we let $V(G)=\{1,2,...,n\}$:

Consider the set $S_n$ of permutations of the vertices in $G$ and $\sigma \in S_n$ be a permutation in $S_n$. Let $A_i$ be the event that $\sigma(i)<\sigma(j), \forall j \in N(i)$ namely all neighbours $j$ of the vertex $i$ gets maps to by $\sigma$ to some number greater than $\sigma(i)$. There are $\binom{n}{1+d_i}$ places that $\sigma$ can map the vertex $i$ and its neighbors to. Futhermore, $\sigma(i)$ is the smallest, so there are $d_i!$ ways for the neighbours of  $i$ to be map to and $(n-d_i-1)!$ ways for the remaining number to be permuted. So $P(A_i)=\frac{\binom{n}{d_i+1} d_i!(n-d_i-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{1+d_i}$. Now consider the subset of the vertex set of $G$, $U=\{i \mid A_i = \text{true}\}$. Notice that two vertices in $U$ does not share an edge. The expected value $E[|U|]=\sum_{i\in \{1,...,n\}}{\frac{1}{1+d_i}}$. So done.

But I'm wondering if there is a proof not involving probabilistic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algorithmic proof is given by Murphy [1, Section 1], where he attributes the algorithm to Erdös [2].

As a side remark, I don't know what the original proof of Caro or Wei is, but I believe the proof you mention is due to Alon and Spencer [3].

---

[1] [Murphy, Owen. "Lower bounds on the stability number of graphs computed in terms of degrees." Discrete Mathematics 90.2 (1991): 207-211.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82699691.pdf)

[2] Erdös, Paul. "On the graph theorem of Turán." Mat. Lapok 21. (1970): 249-251.

[3] Alon, Noga, and Joel H. Spencer. The Probabilistic Method. John Wiley & Sons, 2004.

Comment: Sorry also in the turan's theorem , they mentioned $K_{r-1}$free graph.What is a $k_n$free graph ?

Comment: @mathnoob An $H$-free graph means that it doesn't have a subgraph isomorphic to $H$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several non-probabilisitc proofs :
1/ using greedy algorithm deleting minimum degree :
See : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X13001339
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190150110

2/ deleting vertices of maximum degree :
see :https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i1p33

There are everal more variations.

My original 1999 proof was via induction and deleting vertex of maximum degree.

Answer (score 1):

Induction on the order of G . True for |G| = 1. Assume for |G| = n let prove it for |G| = n +1. Choose a vertex v of minimum degree . Consider H = G - N[v]. Clearly a(G)> = 1 + a(H) > = 1 + sum { 1/( deg_H(u) +1) :u in V(H)} > = ** sum { 1/(deg_G(w)) +1 ) :w in N[{v] } + sum { 1/( deg_H(u) +1) : u in V(H)} = sum { 1/(deg_G(w)) +1 ) : w in N[{v] } + sum { 1/( deg_G(u) +1 : u in V(G)\N[v]}=
sum { 1/(deg(w)+1 ) w in V(G) }. deg_G(w) the degree of w in G , deg_H(u) the degree of u in H. ** observe 1=sum {1/(deg(v)+1 ):w in N[v] } > = sum{ 1/(deg_G(w) +1) : w in N[v] } as v has minimum degree .
Best - Yair Caro .